# Error when reinstalling Ruby with RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm, homebrew

I'm attempting to reinstall ruby, but am getting an error. I've included the error and log below.

The error:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p362
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p362.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary     rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Already up-to-date.
Installing required packages: libtool, libyaml, libxml2, libxslt, libksba, openssl, sqlite............
Error running 'requirements_brew_libs_install libtool libyaml libxml2 libxslt libksba openssl sqlite',
please read /Users/Henry/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p362/package_install_libtool_libyaml_libxml2_libxslt_libksba_openssl_sqlite.log
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation
```

The log file:

```
 cat package_install_libtool_libyaml_libxml2_libxslt_libksba_openssl_sqlite.log
 [2013-03-30 21:07:08] requirements_brew_libs_install
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/libtool/libtool-2.4.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libtool-2.4.2.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2 --program-prefix=g --enable-    ltdl-install
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... ./configure: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed:    /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
no
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh libltdl/config/config.sub
./configure: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
./configure: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you are using a custom version of `sed` => `/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed` and it has broken shebang `/bin/bash^M` - either use native OSX tools or make sure those provided by you are working as expected.